# Tabhost creating trouble in getChildlView method of ExpandableList

Tags: android, listview

I have put tabs insilde a expandablelistview adapter and due to its getCHildView method tabs are generating multiple times in on parent click. How to resolve this .

This is an example of what I need to implement.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvPZe.png

In left side image there is list of expandable view to be shown to user. Once user click on any of the expandable view i need to display tabs inside childlistview  of expandable list view as shown in right image.

Please see below the entire code

My Activity Class

```
public class CardList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_list);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
}
```

Activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private Button b;
    LinearLayout l;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }
    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        final View views = convertView;
        final ViewGroup parents =parent;
        TabHost host = (TabHost)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
        host.addTab(spec);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab Two");
        host.addTab(spec1);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec2.setIndicator("Tab Three");
        host.addTab(spec2);
        host.setFocusable(false);
        host.setup();
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle= (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams firstParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300);
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            int color = Color.argb(255, 104, 224, 201);

            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(firstParam);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton) ;
        img.setFocusable(false);
        System.out.println("headerTitle 123-------------------> "+headerTitle);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("headerTitle -------------------> "+(String) getGroup(groupPosition));
                Intent i = new Intent(_context,DashboardActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("feroz",(String) getGroup(groupPosition));
                _context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    private Button addTextView(){
        Button Button = new Button(_context);
      Button.setText("submit");
        return Button;
    }
}
```

list_group.xml for parent view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#000000"
android:weightSum="100"
    >        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:text="hello "
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/line"
            android:layout_weight="10"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:src="@drawable/launch"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item for child view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
<TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffc916"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 1" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#da8200"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 2" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#5b89ff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 3" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing little amount of research I got to know that the problem is with convert view which you are reusing for the child once it gets created once. But not for the TabHost. You are creating the TabHost every time even if the view is already gets created and also tabhost setup is also done for the same child.I have just edited adapter class and for research one method prepareListData(). SO here is the edited code:-

MyExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter     {
private Context _context;
private Button b;
LinearLayout l;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);

        TabHost host = (TabHost) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();
        Log.e("tab count",""+host.getTabWidget().getTabCount());
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
        host.addTab(spec);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab Two");
        host.addTab(spec1);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec2.setIndicator("Tab Three");
        host.addTab(spec2);
        host.setFocusable(false);
        host.setup();
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle= (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams firstParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300);
        //Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.argb(255, 104, 224, 201);

        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(firstParam);
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    ImageButton img = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton) ;
    img.setFocusable(false);
    System.out.println("headerTitle 123-------------------> "+headerTitle);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("headerTitle -------------------> "+(String) getGroup(groupPosition));
            Intent i = new Intent(_context,DashboardActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("feroz",(String) getGroup(groupPosition));
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private Button addTextView(){
    Button Button = new Button(_context);
    Button.setText("submit");
    return Button;
}
}
```

prepareListData() method

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");
    listDataHeader.add("Item 4..");
    listDataHeader.add("Item 5..");
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), new ArrayList<String>());
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), comingSoon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks praveen i will check this. It help a lot

Comment: Can you please accept the answer and up vote it. You welcome